# Max number of threads for elasticsearch too low

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed elasticsearch 5 on it. Now when I try to start elasticsearch using

```
/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start
```

After a few seconds in the log file I read:

```
[2016-11-19T08:47:31,442][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [shooter-1] node validation exception
bootstrap checks failed
max number of threads [1891] for user [elasticsearch] likely too low, increase to at least [2048]
```

After some googling, I came to the conclusion that I had to add the following line to `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
elasticsearch    -       nproc           2048
```

However, even after this change, I still get the same error.

I found a suggestion to uncomment the line `session    required   pam_limits.so` in `/etc/pam.d/su`, but that line was already uncommented.

What am I missing?

Comment: `nproc` is typically for services and not users. You may have better luck on the unix or superuser stack exchanges as this is a sysadmin question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've opened it at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324504/how-to-raise-max-threads-for-elasticsearch

Comment: Did you restart the server after applying the changes?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible this issue is related to insufficient memory on the machine. I was running into other problems, including this one, all of which were fixed by increasing the amount of memory (from 512MB to 1GB).